Spring Cloud Gateway + Spring Security + Spring Boot 3
We're migrating all our microservices to Spring Boot 3.

Zuul to be migrated to Spring Boot3. Hence Spring-cloud will be the new API Gateway.
Zuul was acting like a resource server(used JWTs + OAuth2) before. What has to be the new security mechanism in Spring boot3? Do we have to use Spring-cloud-gateway in the new security flow to be implemented?

Searched in net but getting confused.Any help would be much appreciated.

You should read that https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

@ch4mp : Thanks for sharing...Oauth2 can be used in spring-boot3 as it is deprecated from Spring Boot 2.7?

They deprecated a lib but provided new implementations. The article linked is about OAuth2...
